# Quanto CDS pricer in Python

Tags: programming, cds, quanto

I am sales and would like to grasp rough levels of quanto CDS, such as BMW denominated in USD, without askin traders each time. What i'm thinking is to calculte it using Python.

But i cannot build up complex codes. Does there exist quanto CDS pricer/library in Python?

Comment: Probably worth using an off-the-shelf solution rather than programming this yourself. Do you have access to e.g. a terminal?

Comment: It is unlikely that the default of BMW will have much to do with the USD/EUR exchange rate. A quanto effect in CDS arises usually when a sovereign defaults on its foreign debt.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Have Bloomberg but DLIB seems to be not working for quanto CDS and technical support is short staffed there.

Comment: Wrt sovreign cds, I understand your logic. But anyway i'd like to how traders price BMW in usd or Barclays in JPY. Ignoring correl with fx, if Barclays 5y cds is 100 bp in eur, iand that eurjpy 5y basis -30, then Barclays cds in jpy is 70bp in theory?

Comment: I think so. Any reasonable trader at your institution should be happy to discuss this before sending you off to a programming task.

Comment: There are three reasons/drivers/explanations for the existence of observable quanto factors: 1 currency devaluation on default to which @KurtG. alludes, 2 difference in risk-free interets rates, 3 technical - supply and demand, for example, someone is putting together a structured trade in USD and is buying/selling USD-denominated BMW protection, and that affects BMW USD much more than it affects BMW EUR quotes, so the quanto factor changes. It's easy to put together a calculation for only the second one - calculate survival probabilities from BMW CDS quotes and EUR interest rate curve (cont)

Comment: then use these survival probabilities and observable USD curve to calculate what the BMW USD CDS quotes would be if there was no difference in supply and demand. The danger is that the third driver can also sometimes affect the quanto factor by a lot.

Comment: To clarify, when your traders tell you the the quanto factor, they may be basing it on the difference in interest rates most of the time, but sometimes they know (or anticipate) that someone is putting together e.g. a USD synthetic CDO, and is trading single-name CDS as hedges for that, and that causes their quanto factor to change. A calculation without this additional information about supply/demand would be  of limited usefulness.

Comment: @KurtG. "A quanto effect in CDS arises usually when a sovereign defaults on its foreign debt. " yes and not only sovereign, but also systemically important corporate/quasi-sovereign credits, e.g. MXN-denominated Pemex,  or CLF-denominated Codelco,or RUB-denominated Gazprom, or ZAR-denominated Eskom... that's what drives such quanto factors to well below 80. But quanto factors not linked to any devaluations on default can still fluctuate in the 95-105 range for other reasons.

Comment: DLIB doesn't do it properly. For the Quanto CDS, you can go to the market data tab where  there is an input box for what the change in FX would be given default and then it will imply a EUR CDS curve. With jump 0 it actually does not revert to the non-quanto curve precisely, though the difference shouldn't be material. Either way, you will have to come up with the parameter yourself (which you might be able to get from your traders because it shouldn't change much).